# Check if picture has white background

Tags: laravel, intervention

How can I detect if a picture has a white background or not using Intervention.

My project is using a lot of picture which are either from studio in a white lab environment, or lifestyle nature images.

I would like to use a script to determine which ones have a white background.
I don't need to change the pictures in any way.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think that Intervention hasn't this function but you can achieve that using python in implement it into the laravel app.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Could you please point me to an example of python script to do that ?

Comment: Your are welcome. https://medium.com/generalist-dev/background-colour-detection-using-opencv-and-python-22ed8655b243